# Configurate the "New Agent" in an Assembler-Block in AnyLogic

Tags: java, simulation, anylogic

I'm new at stackoverflow and I'm a basic AnyLogic user. I have 4 Agents (Product 1,2,3 and Raw Material). In my Assembler-Block 1 Product(Product 1,2 OR 3) (Input1) and 1 Raw Material (Input2) will be assembled. The Problem: My "New Agent" have to be the same Agent as the Agent Input1 was.
[schematic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8XZi6.png)

For example, I have 1x Product2 and 1x Raw Material the "New Agent" of the Assembler have to be Product2.
EDIT: The different Agents get an Id (example:Product1 --> agent.getId()==10)

I can imagine it is a very trivial problem, but I tried to solve it in many ways and couldn't handle it.
I hope you can help me.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Are the 3 products different agent types or the same type?

Comment: The products are different agent types.
There is an Agent type Product1,an Agent type Product2, an Agent typeProduct3 and an Agent type RawMaterial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your products are different agent types but the assembed agent should be the original product, you should not use `Assemble` but `Pickup`. Your products "pickup" 1 RawMaterial agent when they pass through but continue to be Product1, 2 or 3. If you RawMaterial is there, the products queue and wait until it becomes available.